# Why is Hibernate returning stale data for a non cacheable object?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

Hibernate (3.6.5) and EhCache (2.4.2)

VehicleAssembly is a persitence class that has a state transition. As the object goes through various stages, it is updated with the latest status and saved in datastore.

**Example of state transition**

[image]

Now, during the next step when the VehicleAssembly is queried as below the stale status as of '09/24/2013 11:00:30 PM' is returned.

```
query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from VehicleAssembly va where va.assemblyId = ? and assemblyType = ?");
            query.setLong(0, Long.parseLong(refnum));
            query.setString(1, assemblyType);
            VehicleAssembly vaMaster = (VehicleAssembly) query.uniqueResult();
//refNum and assembltType are parameters to the method which has this code
```

Looking at the result it appears hibernate is returning a stale object of VehicleAssembly from the cache. Please note that VehicleAssembly class is NOT cacheable(no @Cache annotation in the class definition). Also, all these updates are happening in different sessions and the isolation level is 2(Read committed) in the datastore.

**VehicleAssembly class is as below**

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "VEHICLES", name =  "ASSEMBLY_MASTER")
@SequenceGenerator(name="idGenerator", sequenceName = "VEHICLES.ASSEMBLY_MASTER_ID_SEQ1", allocationSize=1)
public class VehicleAssembly implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long id;
    private long assemblyId;
    private String assemblyType;
    private String status;
    private Date updateTs;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 16, scale = 0)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "iddGenerator")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "ASSEMBLY_ID", nullable = false, precision = 16, scale = 0)
    public long getAssemblyId() {
        return assemblyId;
    }

    @Column(name = "ASSEMBLY_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 120)
    public String getAssemblyType() {
        return assemblyType;
    }

    @Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false, length = 120)
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_TS", nullable = false, length = 7)
    public Date getUpdateTs() {
        return updateTs;
    }

    //Not addign setters for cosmetic reasons, actually implementation does have setters
```

}

Hibernate second level cache is enabled in the application

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
```

Any pointers on nailing down this ghost object would be of great help.

Comment: Are you sure changes on `VehicleAssemblyv is successfully committed to the db?

Comment: Do you do any transaction management? E.g. @Transactional in spring framework. You need to set some isolation levels. Also make sure that you have committed the data and refreshed the data before presenting it.

Comment: @erencan Yes, the changes are committed to the DB. Example of state transition are actually from the DB.

Comment: @Khush Yes, we use transaction management. The isolation level is set to 2(Read committed) and the data is committed as seen in the DB table.